# How to best handle exceptions thrown within a catch block?

Tags: php

Suppose I have a try/catch block where I need to do some cleanup in the catch block if something bad happens.
Then I want to rethrow the original exception to let the application code handle it.

It could for example be to rollback a database transaction like this:

```
try {
  startTransaction();
  doSomethingThatThrowsAnException();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  rollbackTransaction();
  throw $e;
}
```

Fine, but it is possible that the rollback will fail and throw an exception as well. Then my application will only see the rollback exception and not the original exception. Then I will miss out on the most useful information, which is not good.

So I might change the code to this:

```
try {
  startTransaction();
  doSomethingThatThrowsAnException();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  try {
    rollbackTransaction();
  } catch (Exception $ex) {
    // Do nothing
  }
  throw $e;
}
```

That is better, but now I will not know that the cleanup/rollback failed as well. Maybe there's a bug in the rollback function that I will never find.
I want to get full information about both exceptions.

The best I've come up with so far is creating a new exception, keeping the message about the rollback exception, and sending the original exception as previous:

```
try {
  startTransaction();
  doSomethingThatThrowsAnException();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  try {
    rollbackTransaction();
  } catch (Exception $ex) {
    throw new Exception($ex->getMessage(), $ex->getCode(), $e);
  }
  throw $e;
}
```

But it's not perfect, I still lose some information about the rollback exception, such as its stack trace.

I have also experimented with creating another Exception-class holding both exceptions:

```
try {
  startTransaction();
  doSomethingThatThrowsAnException();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  try {
    rollbackTransaction();
  } catch (Exception $ex) {
    throw new MultiException($e, $ex);
  }
  throw $e;
}

class MultiException extends Exception
{
    private $exceptions = [];

    public function __construct(...$exceptions)
    {
        $this->exceptions = $exceptions;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return implode("\n", $this->exceptions);
    }
}
```

But I'm unsure how well this will play with various logging frameworks. For example it is only possible to override the __toString() method and not for example getTrace().

Is there a better way or some best practice to handle cases like this?

Comment: From design, your rollback should not be able to throw an exception - what is the use case for that?

Comment: If you're throwing an exception inside a catch it means that the current area of code can't handle it and it should be handled by a level further up. If you find yourself in a situation where you throw immediately after catching, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: You had code in place that was supposed to deal with an exceptional situation. That code failed, which now basically becomes your primary error. If the caller did not expect the cleanup code to fail, then it would be entirely correct to have that exception bubble up to the top as an unhandled/unexpected exception.

Comment: @deceze Yes, but it was an application exception that caused the rollback exception to occur. If I do not know the original exception it can be hard to figure out why the rollback exception occurred. So I would prefer to get a stack trace containing the whole chain, similar to how `$previous` parameter to Exception works. The main point here is that I want all information available to be able to debug it easily when something exceptional happens.

Comment: @inetphantom This is code that talks with an external resource (a database) probably with some abstraction layer (PDO). There's always a possibility that something goes wrong, and if it does, I want to know about it.

Comment: What if you simply log the exception first and then do the rollback? That way, even if the rollback fails and throws an exception, you still have a log of the original exception.

Comment: @MER Yes, that is also an option which I have used and might be considered good enough. There are however two problems with it which doesn't make it perfect: 1. The log entry will not have a relation with the other exception, which makes it harder to debug. 2. The code that logs might fail and (god forbid) throw an exception.

Comment: If you try to code for exceptions within exceptions within exceptions, etc, you'd never come to an end of all possible exceptions. I think you are over-engineering this. I say just handle the exceptions you know how to handle and throw the exception up the chain if you cannot (or if another exception occurs).